# Что значит фраза “это вам не это"?

Tags: значения, фраза

Есть разные мемы с этой фразой, но что именно она означает?

Comment: Я не понимаю зачем здесь два раза "это"...

Comment: @shabunc It's a about translation. It's  about meaning and usage. So it's not off-topic.

Comment: Сначала надо это прочитать: [Даниил Хармс, «Не теперь»](http://www.stihi-rus.ru/1/harms/20.htm).

Comment: @Alex.S OK, reopening but removing "как ей пользоваться" part - it's unclear what one supposed to answer on that.

Comment: @shabunc Please read this. http://meta.russian.stackexchange.com/questions/399/an-open-letter-to-shabunc-please-stop

Comment: Еще интереснее. Здесь вам не тут.

Answer (score 18):

It's apparently a [film quote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ef_dGigQK9Q). It's a staple of army-related humour that officers have a problem speaking coherently. **Это вам не это** means something like, "This ain't the, you know", i.e. the second **это** is a filler word that just trails off.

Answer (score -2):

тот кто эту фразу говорил забыл название того термина который он хотел сказать и вместо термина он сказал слово "это". вобщем вместо этого он сказал это. просто у человека проблемы с памятью.

Comment: Думаю, что на форуме, посвящённом русскому языку, нужно придерживаться правил орфографии и пунктуации русского языка. О стилистике тоже, наверное, не стоит забывать.